# Trouble with explorer reading styles

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Hey guys so I am working on a site http://www.prodjsoundlighting.com/ and dev in Chrome.  Now when you go to look in it in firefox and explorer it looks bad, more specific the side nav that drops down when you hover over it.  If you look on the firefox or ex you will see that there are squares next to the list which has been taken care of in the style sheet,  the ul li ul should be display none because that is what it is set at in the style sheet.  There is a black background also in the top and that should not be there.  It also should be position fixed because that is what I defined it as.

If you could give me a hand I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks fine to me. I'm using Firefox and I can't see any list bullets in the sidebar. Did I not understand your question correctly?

Comment: Hmm looks like your right.....just went on another computer and not having that issue.